# Why is $wpdb->insert_id and mysql_insert_id() returning with an extra '1' at the end?

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to retrieve the ID of the AUTO_INCREMENT value of the last query.

My query looks like this:

```
  $result = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( "
    INSERT INTO $table_name
    ( name, season, copyright, description, path )
    VALUES ( %s, %s, %s, %s, %s )", 
    $galleryData['name'], $galleryData['season'], $galleryData['copyright'], $galleryData['description'], $galleryData['path'] ) );

  // Let's output the last autogenerated ID.
  echo $wpdb->insert_id;

  // This returns the same result
  echo mysql_insert_id();
```

Looking at my DB table, I see rows counting from 1 to 24 (24 rows).
But using `$wpdb->insert_id` or `mysql_insert_id()` returns `241`.

Doing new inserts will return 251, 261, 271 and so on. Why do I et the extra '1' at the end?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to Pekka (I'd better stad running a tab on the number of beers I owe him), I figured it out.

Further down the code I got this:

```
  if(!$result)
    _e("[DB error] Ups. Something went wrong when trying to insert the event.");
  else
    echo true;
```

It's the last statement (echo true) that is outputed!

Comment: You're saying that the code above echoes `241241`, `251251`, etc.?

Comment: I'll bet a beer there is something somewhere that outputs a boolean variable (which translates to `1` when echoed).

Comment: No, running EITHER `$wpdb->insert_id` OR `mysql_insert_id()` will return `241`, `251`, `261` and so on. The first to numbers are correct, but then the 1 is added. Looking in MySQL, the highest ID is `26`.

Comment: So then what *does* the code above result in?

Comment: can you try `echo "'".mysql_insert_id()."'";`? If this outputs `'241'` with the 1 wrapped inside the quotes, I'll believe it, but not before ;)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am betting a delicious Kölsch:

[image]

that the reason actually is an `echo` later in the code, that echoes some boolean variable, whose `true` will translate to `1`.

If I am wrong, I shall take the downvotes like a man.

(Forgive the silly answer, it's very late already and I'm still working :)

**Update**: Ahh, joy, I was right!

Comment: Ach ja. Du bist voll korrekt! Next time I go to Germany, I'll buy you a large cold Kölsch ;) Although I am surprised you live in Germany. Pekka sounds very Finish :) And yes, I'm working late too!

Comment: @Steven hey, always welcome! :) I'm half finnish, hence the name. I'm calling it a day soon, `night!